# Unable to fit curves to data points using curve_fit() from scipy because of "Optimal parameters not found" error [python]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, curve-fitting, exponential

I am unable to properly fit a logarithmic and exponential decay curve to my experimental data points, where it is as if the suggested curve fits do not resemble the pattern in my data not even remotely.

I have the following example data:

```
data = {'X':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
],
        'Y':[55, 55, 55, 54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 50, 45, 37, 27, 16, 0
]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X','Y'])
df.plot(x ='X', y='Y', kind = 'scatter')
plt.show()
```

This outputs:
[image]

I then try fitting an exponential decay and logarithmic decay curve to these data points using this code and outputting the root mean square error for each curve:

```
# load the dataset
data = df.values
# choose the input and output variables
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

def func1(x, a, b, c):
    return a*exp(b*x)+c

def func2(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x) + b

params, _  = curve_fit(func1, x, y)
a, b, c = params[0], params[1], params[2]
yfit1 = a*exp(x*b)+c
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((yfit1 - y) ** 2))
print('Exponential decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * exp(x*%.5f)+%.5f' % (a, b, c))
print('RMSE:')
print(rmse)
print('')

params, _  = curve_fit(func2, x, y)
a, b = params[0], params[1]
yfit2 = a * np.log(x) + b
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((yfit2 - y) ** 2))
print('Logarithmic decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * ln(x)+ %.5f' % (a, b))
print('RMSE:')
print(rmse)
print('')

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="y-original")
plt.plot(x, yfit1, label="y=a*exp(x*b)+c")
plt.plot(x, yfit2, label="y=a * np.log(x) + b")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

And I receive this output:
[image]

I then try to using my experimental data, trying these new data points:

```
data = {'X':[0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480
],
        'Y':[2.011399983,1.994139959,1.932761226,1.866343728,1.709889128,1.442674671,1.380548494,1.145193671,0.820646118,
             0.582299012, 0.488162766, 0.264390575, 0.139457758, 0, 0, 0, 0
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X','Y'])
df.plot(x ='X', y='Y', kind = 'scatter')
plt.show()
```

This shows:
[image]

I then try using the previous code to fit an exponential decay curve and a logarithmic decay curve to these new data points with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, exp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the dataset
data = df.values
# choose the input and output variables
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

def func1(x, a, b, c):
    return a*exp(b*x)+c

def func2(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x) + b

params, _  = curve_fit(func1, x, y)
a, b, c = params[0], params[1], params[2]
yfit1 = a*exp(x*b)+c
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((yfit1 - y) ** 2))
print('Exponential decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * exp(x*%.5f)+%.5f' % (a, b, c))
print('RMSE:')
print(rmse)
print('')

params, _  = curve_fit(func2, x, y)
a, b = params[0], params[1]
yfit2 = a * np.log(x) + b
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((yfit2 - y) ** 2))
print('Logarithmic decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * ln(x)+ %.5f' % (a, b))
print('RMSE:')
print(rmse)
print('')

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="y-original")
plt.plot(x, yfit1, label="y=a*exp(x*b)+c")
plt.plot(x, yfit2, label="y=a * np.log(x) + b")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

And I receive this output which looks totally wrong:
[image]

And then I receive this plotted output which looks very far off from my experimental data points:
[image]

I do not understand why my first curve fitting attempt worked so well and smoothly, while my second attempt seems to have turned into a huge incoherent mess that just broke the curve_fit function. I do not understand why I see the graph going into the negative y-axis if I do not have any negative y-axis values in my experimental data. I am confused because I can clearly see my experimental data plotted fine as just points, so I am not sure what is so wrong about it that I cannot simply fit my curves to the points. How can I address my code so that I can properly use curve_fit() to fit an exponential decay curve and a logarithmic decay curve to my experimental data points?

Comment: The second dataset looks rather like a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: First, the warning from curve_fit says it encountered overflows (i.e. produced values that are too large for a variable to contain) which is not suprising as your model assumption contains exponential and does not look right for the data. A necessary step to better avoid this situation is to use the right model assumption. As Mr.T said, your data looks more like a sigmoid function, or sigma(c-x) I would say, so you need to use function like that for curve_fit. If curve_fit overflows, you can't trust any result from that.

Comment: @RaymondKwok - Ah ok, so if I see an overflow returned, I can know that that particular curve was not a good fit for my data. I am just trying to understand which specific metric to go by to determine if the fit is not good, such as what would be helpful if I were iterating over my curve fitting attempts, and need a simple way to record whether the fit was acceptable or not. I am guessing that if I see an RMSE of "inf", then this would mean the fit is unacceptable, though I am confused about how I have an infinite RMSE though.

Comment: RMSE is certain a useful aggregated number, and other single number indicators such as R2. Another, perhaps more useful but requires more of your attention, is graphical way such as really plotting the fitted line and data; plotting the residuals; or making a Q-Q plot. I always recommend the graphical way unless you are pretty sure that your model assumption is very close to the data generation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments the model seems on the logistic kind.

The main difficulty for fitting with the usual softwares is the choice of the initial values of the parameters to start the iterative calculus. A non conventional method which general principle is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales doesn't need initial values. For example the numerical calculus is shown below :

[image]

With your second data :

[image]

With your first data :

[image]

If you want a more accurate fit according to some specified criteria of fitting (MSE, MSRE, MAE, or other) you could take the above values of parameters as starting values in a non-linear regression software.